# Manual for updating JSF 2.0 Project to 2.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

unfortunately there are no working tutorials to update a Eclipse (KEPLER) JSF 2.0 Project to JSF 2.2.
Should this update be done or should a new project be created (and import all files)?

What are the Steps to update the used JSF version properly and clean?

I'm just getting errors (from FactoryNotFound to StartupServletContextListener problems), when I change the faces.xml header to:

```
<faces-config
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
```

I additionally updated the library to Majorra 2.2.0 (JSF 2.2) and dynamic web project to 3.0 and java to 1.7 (in the preferences), but the server just prints errors and does not work...

Comment: Hi, i have tried applying http://qussay.com/2013/09/14/create-jsf-2-2-maven-project-with-primefaces-3-5-using-eclipse/ and some other approaches, but it doesn't let me switch my jsf version in the project settings to 2.2 (i am using 2.0 now)

Comment: Again, what are the exact problems you're facing when doing this? Any error message you can provide so we can do a further analysis?

Comment: Hi. the questions in detail are: What changes do I have to make in my web.xml, faces.xml, libraries, ...?

Comment: The answer is: update configurations from 2.0 to 2.2. As simple as that.

Answer (score 13):

From the JSF 2.2. Reference implementation manual

> Faces 2.2 is backwards compatible with Faces 2.1 and 2.0. This means that a web-application that was developed to run
>   with Faces 2.1 or 2.0 won’t require any modification when run with Faces 2.2
>
> Due to an error in previous versions of the specification, exceptions were silently being swallowed that now will
>   bubble up to the exception handler. Code that was relying on this incorrect behavior may need to be modified to
>   account for fixing this problem.

And also:

> Any additional attributes on `<composite:attribute/>` are exposed as attributes accessible from the
>   `getValue()` and `attributeNames()` methods on `PropertyDescriptor`. The return type from `getValue()`
>   must be a ValueExpression with the exception of the getValue(“type”). The return type from
>   `getValue(“type”)` must be Class. If the value specified for the type attribute of `<cc:attribute/>`
>   cannot be converted to an actual Class, a `TagAttributeException` must be thrown, including the `Tag` and
>   `TagAttribute` instances in the constructor.

**Conclusion**: there is minimal breakage between JSF2.1. and 2.2.

EDIT: Some new things in JSF2.2:

1. **New namespaces**: 
   `xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"` can replace `xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"` and also

   `xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"` can replace `xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"`
2. **Based on your comment**:
   The `preRenderView` event type from the following construct in JSF2.0:

   ```
   <f:metadata>
      <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{viewActionManagedBean.validateUser()}"/>
   </f:metadata>
   ```

   Can be replaced with the following brand new `<f:viewAction/>` tag in JSF2.2:

   ```
   <f:metadata>
       <f:viewAction action="#{viewActionManagedBean.validateUser()}"/>
   </f:metadata>
   ```

   This tag also provides support for executing the managed bean method during specific phases of the request lifecycle with the `phase` attribute. Valid options are

   - RESTORE_VIEW (Restore View)
   - APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES(Apply Request Values)
   - PROCESS_VALIDATIONS(Process Validations)
   - UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES(Update Model Values)
   - INVOKE_APPLICATION(Invoke Application)
   - RENDER_RESPONSE(Render Response)

   The tag also supports the `if` attribute that defines a boolean condition on which the action will be run. Take the following for example:

   ```
   <f:metadata>
      <f:viewAction action="#{viewActionManagedBean.validateUser()}" if="#{viewActionManagedBean.verifyCondition}" phase="APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES"/>
   </f:metadata>
   ```

   Note that this tag is available only in the new namespace `xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"`

You can get your copy of the specification below. Look under the **/Preface/Changes between 2.1. and 2.2. /Backwards Compatibility with Previous Versions**

- http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr344/index.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The thing is that I want to use JSF2.2 components like f:viewAction (currently Im running jsf 2.0 as you see in the title). Also I am trying to provide for all other people having the same problem a good tutorial to update from 2.0 to 2.2. So do I just need to change namespaces or are there other files to include/update?

Comment: @Niko - At this point, you need to state specifically the problem you're facing. I will update the answer with a few tidbits that may be helpful but in general, replacing the jar should suffice.

Comment: Hi. I need all steps (changes web.xml, faces.xml, libraries, project settings) to change the 2.0 project to a 2.2 project. currently i am just getting errors during tomcat start concerning "Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester"... every solved problem creates two new...

Comment: Or is it better to create a new project with 2.2 settings and import all data?

Comment: @Niko -Your question is getting muddier with every comment. the few lines of exception you've posted here indicates your web app was built using Myfaces for JSF2.0, yet in your question, you're saying you updated the webapp with a Mojarra distribution for JSF2.2. So your question is not just about moving from 2.0 to 2.2, you're also changing JSF implementations. Obviously that's going to be messy. Start a project afresh with mojarra

Comment: Damn, I've spent at least 3 days trying to figure out why my JSF pages weren't being rendered and it was a wrong namespace -_- amazing

Comment: Looking at [JSF 2.2 source code](https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.9/jsf-api/src/main/java/javax/faces/component/UIViewAction.java), phases availables are not all of them: `ANY_PHASE`, `RESTORE_VIEW` or `RENDER_RESPONSE` cannot be used.

Comment: Not according to [this source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.faces/javax.faces-api/2.2/javax/faces/event/PhaseId.java#PhaseId) @datakey

Comment: Maybe we are not talking about the same. You're linking `PhaseId` class, not the `f:viewAction` component implementation. And [GC says the same](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.faces/javax.faces-api/2.2/javax/faces/component/UIViewAction.java#UIViewAction.setPhase%28java.lang.String%29) as [Mojarra official javadocs](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/javadocs/javax/faces/component/UIViewAction.html#setPhase%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: You didn't provide any context in your comment; I'd assumed you were referring to the phases available in a general JSF application. It appears you were referring to the phases available only in the `viewAction` @datakey

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the prototype of faces-config by :

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <faces-config 
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
 version="2.2">`
```

Then: select your web project, right click > property > Project facets > deselect jsf version > press ok.

Finaly : right click on your project than maven > update project ...

Restart your server ...

I hope that it help, it work for me

Comment: See the first quoted line in the answer by @Kolossus: _"Faces 2.2 is backwards compatible with Faces 2.1 and 2.0. This means that a web-application that was developed to run with Faces 2.1 or 2.0 won’t require any modification when run with Faces 2.2 "_